# Excel - VBA : automatically replace words with another (using What/Replacement)

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I would like my code to automatically replace some words from a list by other words. 
So far, I found how to replace one word by another. For example, if I want the word "Avenue" to be replaced by the word "Ave." I use :

```
Worksheets("sMain").Columns("D").Replace _
What:="Avenue", Replacement:="Ave.", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

It works.
Now I would like to make it more efficient by replacing more than one word by another. For example, if I type "Avenue" or "avenue" or "ave.", it will be replaced by "Ave.".
I have been trying this but with no success (compilation error) :

```
Worksheets("sMain").Columns("D").Replace _
What:="Avenue", Replacement:="Ave.", _
What:="avenue", Replacement:="Ave.", _
What:="ave.", Replacement:="Ave.", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

Any idea on how to make it possible? 
Thanks

Comment: 3 replace statements of the first form?.....

Comment: So if in the input the user writes "Avenue" or "avenue", or even "ave." (which i can't predict, it depends on its own habits), my program is just gonna identify this as "Ave." which is the word I use in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in a loop like this

```
ary = Array("Avenue", "avenue", "ave.")
For Each wd In ary
    Columns("D").Replace What:=wd, Replacement:="Ave.", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
Next
```

You may also like to set MatchCase to False as you won't need the two upper and lower case "avenue"'s .

Comment: Thanks for the help, in principle it should work but I experience the weirdest problem when trying it. When I type "avenue" or "Ave.", I have a wrong replacement. It's replaced by "Ave.." instead of "Ave." with one more ".". On the other hand, when I type "ave", it works fine. So weird.

Comment: Make sure your replacement strings are not also substrings. For instance if you are replacing "ave" with "ave." then things that were orginally "ave." will become "ave.."

Comment: That was indeed it, thanks! One last question, it's not really important as declaring variables isn't an obligation, but what is the kind of variable for ary and wd? I tried Dim ary As Array but there is not such thing as array in the list of choices. And I tried wd as String but it didn't work.

Comment: ary is an array of strings, DIM ary() as string, variables in For Each (like wd here) must be varient

Comment: Ignore the above, ary is an inline array so must also be variant, just DIM ary()