# automatically changing cell value

Tags: excel

I have Column A which includes variable amount of Different values but also includes following three values; "Kurz", "Stein", "Neuer".

What I want to do is following; If cell Value is "Kurz" then I want that value automatically changed to "Team1". If its "Stein" then "Team2" and if its "Neuer" then "Team3". If its some other value then I don't want anything to happen.

Maybe something like this should work but I don't now how to code this;

```
  If ValueA1= "Kurz" then ValueA1= "Team1"
```

How can code this right?

Comment: Are you planning on using VBA or wanting to avoid it?

Comment: if it works without using vba that would be also good. i mean if Excel has automatical functions, which directly writes for "Kurz", "Team1" and so on..

Comment: If you don't mind VBA then you can probably apply [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016085/excel-vba-automatically-replace-words-with-another-using-what-replacement).

Can't think of any way with formulas that doesn't involve creating a new column, which would then just be a simple IF statement. You can always use find and replace as well, but I'm presuming you want to avoid that?

Comment: this somehow makes sense, but however it still Looks chinese to me. How can i use that code for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to to do it with some simple VBA code, not sure if it is the most efficient, but it should get the job done!

```
Sub replaceWords()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Kurz" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = "Team 1"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = "Stein" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = "Team 2"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = "Neuer" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = "Team 3"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```